# Process for importing event data nightly that has ID's that recycle every 45 days with a max and min value per ID

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following data that I need to devise a better way to process. We are currently tracking events that have a format like so:

```
|scaneventID|scandatetime       |status   |scanfacilityzip|
+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------------+
|isdijh23452|2020-01-01 13:45:12|Intake   |12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-01 13:45:12|Intake   |12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-01 19:30:32|Received |12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-02 04:50:22|Confirmed|12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-03 19:32:18|Processed|45867          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-01 10:24:16|Intake   |84676          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-01 19:30:32|Received |84676          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-01 19:30:32|Received |84676          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-02 02:15:52|Processed|84676          |
```

And I need to trim this down so that each scan event has an intake and a processed scan event like so:

```
|scaneventID|scandatetime       |status   |scanfacilityzip|
+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------------+
|isdijh23452|2020-01-01 13:45:12|Intake   |12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-03 19:32:18|Processed|45867          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-01 10:24:16|Intake   |84676          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-02 02:15:52|Processed|84676          |
```

And insert them into a huge table. However there can be up to 10 scan events per scanEventID and all scanEventIDs are recycled and reused every 45 days. We receive hundreds of thousands of events per day, and right now I am taking the raw data, filtering to the last 45 days, making one dataframe with the minimum scandatetime and one with the maximum scandatetime and `status = processed`, unioning them, inserting them into my table, and then running the following queries:

```
DELETE   FROM scans T1
  USING       scans T2
WHERE T1.scandatetime>(current_timestamp - interval '21 days')
  AND  T1.ctid   < T2.ctid     -- delete the "older" ones
  AND  T1.scaneventID    = T2.scaneventID      -- list columns that define duplicates
  AND  T1.scandatetime = T2.scandatetime
;

delete from scans
    where scandatetime>(current_timestamp - interval '21 days') and
          scandatetime <> (select min(tt.scandatetime) from scans tt where tt.scaneventID = scans.scaneventID) and
          scandatetime <> (select max(tt.scandatetime) from scans tt where tt.scaneventID = scans.scaneventID)
;
```

To delete duplicates and retain only the maximum and minimum scandatetimes.

This process works, but it is painfully slow and inefficient. How can I go about speeding it up? Raw scan data is stored as parquet in S3, I am processing it with PySpark in AWS Glue, and writing it to a Postgres database in a VPC.

Because I am using Postgres, I can't use things like `preactions` and `postactions` in Glue to run SQL queries after uploading, which makes me unable to load them into a staging table first. I also cannot upsert because there's no unique identifier since the scanEventIDs recycle every 45 days.